# Triple store for developing a comercial application

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, rdfs, triplestore

I am developing a semantic web application and I am using some open source triple stores, during the development stage. However, I need to chose some triple store for being used in the final (comercial) product.

What is the most suitable open source triple store that I can use in my application, without having to make available my application as open source too?

I am considering that my application has an abstraction layer that can be linked to different triple stores. However, I would like to distribute the application with one (or more) triple store (s).

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the kind of question that StackOverflow is designed for - tool comparisons and recommendations tend to become quite partisan quickly.

However, a few links that list or compare triple stores - only the first pone provides a direct comparison between performance of different implementations.

https://www.bioontology.org/wiki/images/6/6a/Triple_Stores.pdf

https://www.w3.org/wiki/LargeTripleStores

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_subject-predicate-object_databases

Comment: Hi Ignazio. Thank you for replying. I have already reviewed these links that you provided. My goal with this post was to get some suggestions of people with the same problem, but without any discussion about preferences. Just a list of triple stores that could be included in my product (without the necessity of licensing it as source code) would be good.